# PHP Regex to find images with specific src attribute

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable with HTML source and I need to find images within the variable that contain images with specific src attributes.

For example my image:

```
<img src="/path/img1.svg">
```

I have tried the below but doesnt work, any suggestions?

```
$hmtl = '<div> some stuff <img src="/path/img1.svg"/> </div><div>other stuff</div>';
preg_match_all('/<img src="/path/img1.svg"[^>]+>/i',$v, $images);
```

Comment: [HTML is not a language that can be parsed by RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: You should escape each occurence of slash (`/`) inside your regex since it used as regex delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class, not regular expressions when it comes to parsing HTML.

```
<?php
$html='<img src="/path/img1.svg">';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src'); //"prints" /path/img1.svg
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can create a new `DOMXPath` object and do an xpath query for `//img[@src='foo']`

Comment: I have updated the question. I am trying to get all images with a specific image src from some sourcecode, not just the src from img

Comment: Thanks for modifying the question late.. (I personally hate that :P) Anyways..That example is not enough , Can you post your HTML content and show us your expected output ?